# WTForms error: "object.__new__() takes no parameters", when setting additional kwargs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, wtforms, keyword-argument

Gathering from what I've seen, I'm guessing you're supposed to pass kwargs to WTForms widget and it will add them as attributes to the tag, right? Like so?

```
from wtforms import Form, TextAreaField, validators
from wtforms.widgets import TextArea

class ContactForm(Form):
    body = TextAreaField('Message', [validators.Required()], widget=TextArea(rows=25, cols=50))
```

Well, what I get in my console is the following:

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

After a few hours of research and trepidation, I'm not quite sure what to make of this error. The TextArea widget source says the following:

> `rows` and `cols` ought to be passed as keyword args when rendering.

Seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

I'm using Python 2.7 in App Engine, along with Flask, if that helps any. I'm using the latest version of WTForms, 1.0.1 as of the time of writing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set cols and rows in your HTML:

`{{form.text(cols="45", rows="10", placeholder=_('Please describe in a few simple sentences'))|safe}}`

And then call your widget with no parameters `()`

Comment: That's a good idea. I'm using the render_field form macro on this page: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/wtforms/
It's nice and concise. Of course, I can easily just replace the call to the function to something more verbose, like yours. It might be a good idea to just know how to do that without the macro. Thanks.

Comment: Works great, but I had to remove the underscore next to placeholder. Was that supposed to serve a particular purpose?

Comment: @CryptoQuick: Yes, the underscore was there if you have a translating mechanism then the underscore instructs the framework to translate the argument to the function. I hope this clarifies the purpose of the underscore.

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know about gettext. This is something I'll keep in mind for future projects. Thanks for the clarification, Nick.